# Why is this set a basis for $R^2$? Is my reasoning correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading this text and I just want to verify that this set of vectors is a basis and that my logic is correct for why the systems have a unique solution.

Here is the text:

[image]

So we have the set $S = {(1,1), (1, -1)}$ and we're trying to see if it's basis for $R^2$

A basis is achieved if the set (1) spans $R^2$ and if it's (2) linearly independent.

Focus on the first yellow highlight. So first onto why it spans $R^2$. It spans $R^2$ because:

- The coefficient matrix is \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} and so the determinant is -2 right?
- And the logic is that if the determinant is nonzero, then it's invertible, and then it has a unique solution. Are these the relevant theorems:

[image]

and

[image]

and

[image]

Are those the relevant theorems? (As an aside, if you try to find a matrix B that is row-equivalent A and you find out that the the determinant of B is not 0, why does this imply that the determinant of A is not 0?

For the second yellow highlight, the solution is trivial similar to how this solution is trivial right:

[image]

Comment: The [invertible matrix theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html) contains a long list of conditions, each of which are necessary and sufficient for a matrix to be invertible.  It is common for half or so of these conditions to be proven to you as examples and the remaining half of the conditions to be homework for you to prove yourself.  Among the conditions, you cited a number of specific results from the invertible matrix theorem that do indeed imply what you want, namely that the rows (or columns) of your matrix are linearly independent.

Comment: As for why if $A$ and $B$ are row equivalent (*square*) matrices and $\det(B)\neq 0$ then this implies $\det(A)\neq 0$., you can see this by noting $A$ is row equivalent to $B$ if and only if there exist elementary matrices $E_1,E_2,\dots,E_k$ such that $A=E_1E_2\cdots E_k B$ and so $\det(A)=\det(E_1)\det(E_2)\cdots \det(E_k)\det(B)$, noting further that $\det(E)\neq 0$ for each elementary matrix and $\det(B)\neq 0$ implies that $\det(A)\neq 0$.